# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXFjD.png)
I take (Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)) error. How can ı solve this error. Help me please , I cant use sqlite in ionic2. You can send me any ionic 2 sqlite example in github.

Thanx from now.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { KanalyaratPage } from '../pages/kanalyarat/kanalyarat';
import { KanalPage } from '../pages/kanallistele/kanallistele';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { DbProvider } from '../providers/db/db';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TaskServiceProvider } from '../providers/task-service/task-service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    KanalyaratPage,
    KanalPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    KanalyaratPage,
    KanalPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Storage,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    DbProvider,
    DbProvider,
    SQLitePorter,
    SQLite,
    TaskServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

kanallistele.ts(home.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DbProvider } from '../../providers/db/db';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'kanallistele.html',
})
export class KanalPage {
  developers = [];
  developer = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , private databaseProvider : DbProvider) {
    this.databaseProvider.getDatabaseState().subscribe(rdy =>{
      if(rdy)
        {
          this.loadDeveloperData();
        }
    })

    }

   loadDeveloperData() {
    this.databaseProvider.getAllDevelopers().then(data => {
      this.developers = data;
    })
  }

    addDeveloper()
    {
      this.databaseProvider.addDeveloper(this.developer['name'],this.developer['skill'],this.developer['yearsOfExperience'])
      .then(data =>{
        this.loadDeveloperData();
      });
      this.developer ={};
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)

You don't have to add Storage (from ionic-native) to the 'providers' array from the NgModule.

Comment: if I don't add Storage at NgModule , I take this errror (Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Storage!
Error: No provider for Storage!)